# Unusual and sudden slow login and lock screen in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, performance, login, lock

I have Windows 7 Professional on my laptop (since 2011, not updated). It was working fine, but suddenly the login screen has an unusually long please wait time, and lock screen takes about a minute or longer to appear after pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. The rest is working OK.

1. I have checked fragmentation (about 6%). I hope it does not need to be defragged.
2. This problem does not occur in safe mode.
3. Bare minimum startup items (antivirus and graphics driver)
4. PC performance is good, no other slowdowns, not even in UAC.

Any suggestions? Any other info needed?

Comment: solved it ... 

fast access  credential service was disabled . which solved the problem for lock screen 

this is a software for face recognition and other credentials to be provided at logon time usually shipped with dell laptops /

Comment: If you've solved your own question, please post an answer below so others can benefit from your experience. Thank you.

Comment: less reputation ..cant answer till 1st 8 hrs ... will do it soon :)

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that the Fast Access Credential service was disabled. Enabling it solved the problem with the lock screen.

This is software usually shipped with Dell laptops for providing face recognition or other credentials at logon.

To re-enable it:

1. Go to run prompt (Win+R or use Start menu search)
2. Type `services.msc` and press Enter
3. Set `faservice` to Automatic in its properties and click Apply.
4. Start `faservice`

Similar finger print recognition and other biometric credential software may be installed on your system.  Check whether the relevant service is running or not. Alternatively you can uninstall such software but do so at your own risk.

It applies to me as there was no apparent fragmentation and other system slow down than the mentioned. I got some information from the Event Logs which indicated the failure of loading a DLL related to the FA software.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer!